# How to make the recyclerview uses an arraylist from a specific index

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview inside a fragment and the data coming via web request.!
what I want is to ignore the first 3 items of the data array, I just want it to start from index 3.!

I think it would be solved using `homeData.sublist(0,2)` but I don't know where exactly to put this line..! I've tried several places but didn't work..!?

**My Fragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {

  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  ArrayList<Home.HomeItem> homeData;
  private HomeAdapter adapter;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    InitRecyclerView();
    GetData();
    return rootView;
  }

  private void GetData() {

      WebRequests.HomeRequest(new OnRequestResults() {
        @Override
        public void OnSuccess(Object o) {

          ArrayList<Home.HomeItem> homeList = (ArrayList<Home.HomeItem>) o;
          homeList.subList(0, 2); // tried here, but it didn't work

          homeData.clear();
          homeData.addAll(homeList);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } 
 }

  private void InitRecyclerView() {

    homeData = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

     homeList.subList(0, 2); // tried here, it gives carsh `IndexOutofBound..`

    adapter = new HomeAdapter(homeData, getActivity());
    recyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

My Adapter

```
//code

@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    data.subList(0, 2); //noting changes here too

    holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
    Picasso.with(context)
           .load(data.get(position)
           .getImgUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
           .into(holder.pic);
   }

    //code
```

**Update -------------------------------------------------------------------**

I was using .subList wrong, I must specify the start and the end on the new list inside the parameters, I was adding the limits that I wanna remove which's completely stupid !

also I added the line here inside the onSuccess !

```
@Override
        public void OnSuccess(Object o) {
          ArrayList<Home.HomeItem> home = (ArrayList<Home.HomeItem>) o;
          homeData.clear();
          homeData.addAll(home.subList(3,home.size())); //here
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- if you want to **SKIP** first 3 elelemts, then your range is wrong. (0,2) will get you first 3 elements, it should be **(2, list.size()-1)**

2- calling this line `homeList.subList(...)` will not change the list itself, it will return a List that you need to use.
so the code may look like this.

```
homeData.clear();
if(homeList.size() >= 2){ // make sure array has at least 3 elements, (which is going to be skipped)
    homeData.addAll(homeList.subList(2, homeList.size()));
}
```

Note: i am not sure about `fromIndex` (2) if you still see 3rd item in the list, then use 3, in both IF-statement and in subList()

Comment: you were right I was misusing `subList`, I figured that out before I saw ur answer, but it's the correct answer.!

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
 private void initRecyclerView(ArrayList<Home.HomeItem> list) {
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    adapter = new HomeAdapter(list.subList(0, 2), getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }




private void GetData() {
      WebRequests.HomeRequest(new OnRequestResults() {
        @Override
        public void OnSuccess(Object o) {

          ArrayList<Home.HomeItem> homeList = (ArrayList<Home.HomeItem>) o;

          initRecyclerView(homeList);
        } 
 }
```

[List subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) returns the modified list but don't modify the original list. so you calling  `homeList.subList(0, 2);` is dosn't do nay thing.

Comment: it gives me this `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line `adapter = new HomeAdapter(list.subList(0, 2), getActivity());
`

Comment: this means your array is smaller than two.
make sure your ArrayList is retrieved correctly by logging it or by using the debugger.

Comment: inside `InitRecyclerView` it says 0 inside the `onSuccess` it's 20  !

Comment: don't call `initRecyclerView` in `onCreateView`

Comment: It's ok, I found a solution it, see the Update!

Answer (score 1):

`subList` method returns a new `List`. so if you want to use that method, you should do something like this: 
`data = data.subList(0,2);`

you can also keep your list and manipulate your adapter to show items from a specific index. you should implement `getItemCount` and return `data.size() - 3` and in your `onBindViewHolder`, get data from `position - 3`.

Comment: where exactly do I put this, `getItemCount` returns a crash and the same inside the constructor  ?

Comment: implement `getItemCount` in your Adapter class.
please paste your adapter class and logcat.

Comment: It's ok, I found a solution it, see the Update!